# Sign-Magnitude Binary Equivelent in Python

Tags: python, binary

I am trying to write a function in python to convert a decimal number to a binary number in python using sign-magnitude. The function is passed the decimal value and the number of bits. I did not want to use the `bin()` function as I was trying to get my head around the arithmetic.

Comment: um... why is adding the missing 0 stupid? i you are specifying the number of bits to represent it in you will need to add extra `0`s to make it match length, no?

Comment: It will, however shouldn't there be a better way to do it?

Comment: I couldn't thank of one of the top of my head but it seems @Blckknght did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only getting 15 bits because that's all you need to represent `number` (and its sign) in binary. Your `while` loop quits as soon as `number` is zero, even if that hasn't used up all the bits yet. You may want to change it to use a `for` loop on a `range` based on the number of bits instead.

```
for _ in range(bits - 1):
    rem = number % 2
    s.push(rem)
    number = number // 2
```

You might also use `divmod` here to do both the division and modulus in a single operation.